# express * all routes never runs with create react app when using app.use(express.static)

Tags: reactjs, express, create-react-app

I'm using CRA and running an express app but when I run the express app localhost:8080 to render my index.html file it never runs app.get("*"). It seems to be hitting the use static and loading the html from there.

Any ideas on what this might be happening ?

**server/index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || "8080";
const app = express();

const indexPath = path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html");
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../build")));

app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "welcome to backend" });
});

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  console.log("sending index.html");
  res.sendFile(indexPath);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`listing on port ${PORT}`));
```

My folder structure is.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../build")));
```

finds a match for the incoming request in your build directory, then it will handle the request and the routes you have that follow will never get a chance to serve the incoming request.  That's how `express.static()` works.  If you have a route that you don't want `express.static()` to match, then make sure that there is no file that matches the path of the incoming route in your static directory structure.

In the particular case you mention, if `express.static()` sees a request for `/`, then it will look for `index.html` in the directory you gave `express.static()` and if it finds that there, it will just serve it and finish the request.

You can control whether it matches `/` to `index.html` in a couple ways.  First, if there is no `index.html` in that `build` directory, then `express.static()` won't find it.  Or, second, you can pass a configuration option `{index: false}` to `express.static()` to tell it you don't want it to serve `index.html` for `/` like this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../build"), {index: false}));
```

In your specific case, it's unclear why any of this is a problem because your route:

```
const indexPath = path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html");

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  console.log("sending index.html");
  res.sendFile(indexPath);
});
```

Just sends the same `index.html` file either way.

FYI, it's generally not considered wise to send `index.html` for any url request that is otherwise matched as you are going with `app.get('*', ...)` because it is more difficult for search engines and other robotic crawlers to tell which pages actually exist on your site and which don't.  You probably also don't want users bookmarking a non-existent URL that just happens to work as that page may change into some other real content or some other purpose some time in the future.

Comment: {index: false} worked nicely thanks. Not sure i understand your FYI ? could you give me an example of how to use it properly ?  Its a CRA single page app so it needs to load the index.html for all routes.

Comment: @me-me - If the incoming URL doesn't match any actual page you have, you can return a 404 response with an appropriate (no content here) page.  That tells everyone that (including crawling bots) that there's no content at this URL.

Comment: But I want it to catch all urls and load an index.html file. I could have dynamic routes that get handled on the front end with react router. example: localhost:8080/collection/10

Comment: @me-me - I'm just advising you some of the reasons why serving `index.html` for all possible URLs, including all the ones that don't actually exist is not considered a generally good idea.  If you still want to choose to do that despite that advice or you think you have a really good reason for doing so, you can - I'm not stopping you.  Routes that only exist client-side won't work with search engines.

Comment: I understand your saying it’s bad practice. So you suggest only adding routes for the html that match what I need in my app and any other routes that don’t match send user to a 404. Is that why you are suggesting  ?

Comment: @me-me - A route that has no actual content of its own (thus the route doesn't really exist) should give a 404.  The 404 status can still return a web page such that if a user mis-types in the browser, you still give them something helpful, but it shouldn't be `index.html` - it should be a page that tells them this is not a valid url and give them one or more links to click on to go to `index.html` or wherever you want to help them go.